# What is php equivalent of Reduce in javascript to filter the duplicate entries in Array?

Tags: javascript, php

I am filtering array which have same value for key
E.g
***Javascript***

```
var sims = [{icon:"sim"},{icon:"airtime"},{icon:"sim"}]
sims.reduce((a,v)=>{
  var exists = a.some((i)=>{
    return i.icon == v.icon
  })
  if(!exists){
    a.push(v);
  }
  return a
},[])
```

So above code works perfectly fine and I got output
[image: Output of javascript code]

But I am unable to do same thing in php
I have use php array_reduce function but I am not able to understand its working as I am more puzzled with it's syntax

This is what i tried
***Php***

```
<?php
$cars = array(array("icon"=>'sim'),array("icon"=>'airtime'),array("icon"=>'sim')); 
$container = array();
$unique_types = array_unique(array_map(function($elem){return $elem['icon'];}, $cars));

echo json_encode($unique_types);

?>
```

Which gives me output

```
["sim","airtime"]
```

It is giving me unique items which I want but not returning me the whole object as in Javascript.
What am I missing?

Comment: What you're thinking of _would_ be called `array_uunique()`, as in "unique according to a user-defined comparison function", but that function was never implemented because, and I quote: "it looks like a typo".

Comment: @ChrisG yes I am getting unique elements with it I have also tried just returning the $elem but it then just return first key value pair

Comment: @Sammitch I am unable to find uunique instead I only find unique, even in w3schools list of functions
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp

Comment: You could just use `array_unique($cars, SORT_REGULAR)` to achieve this same thing. [See it working here](https://3v4l.org/q9I7k). As per the docs, `SORT_REGULAR` flag: "compare items normally (don't change types)"

Comment: @Jaquarh It  is working thank you so much. Kindly mention the source so i am able to understand it more clearly

Comment: small question about the JS: why would you use `reduce` to do `filter`'s job? `arr.filter((v, pos) => arr.findIndex(e => e.icon === v.icon) === pos)`, done: "only keep any element who's position in the array is the position of the first match for that kind of thing". Also, don't use `var`, you want the modern `let` for reassignables, and `const` for one-time variable assignment. And lastly, one-liner arrow functions auto return, so don' t use `(...) => { return something; }`, just use `(...) => something`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans At this moment I will just say that it was the way I learnt it I also tried with filters as you mentioned but went with reduce as I was unable to crack with filters.

Comment: Too many SO answers about filtering out duplicates from JS arrays with perfectly working code to not succeed at that part, just copy and paste from any of them =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
Yeah, I know anyways thanks for suggesting filters, now i realize i was just one step closer and i went with reduce.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this multiple ways, since your array never changes, you can use the `SORT_REGULAR` flag to [compare items normally](https://3v4l.org/q9I7k).

```
// [{"icon":"sim"},{"icon":"airtime"}]
echo json_encode(array_unique($cars, SORT_REGULAR));
```

This is referenced in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) under "FLAGS".

---

The above will [only compare that the entire array is the same](https://3v4l.org/3sRDD). If your array gets bigger, you may want to [only unique based on the `icon` key](https://3v4l.org/QkJXn).

```
// [{"icon":"sim"},{"icon":"airtime"}]
echo json_encode(array_intersect_key($cars, array_unique(array_column($cars, 'icon'))));
```

You can read up on [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php). Essentially, `array_column` is doing your `array_map` logic which then the only thing you was missing is then mapping those keys back.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this - for instance, try this:

```
$cars = array(
  array("icon"=>'sim'),
  array("icon"=>'airtime'),
  array("icon"=>'sim')); 

echo json_encode(array_map("unserialize",
              array_unique(array_map("serialize", $cars))));
```

Please check the documentation of these functions, the explanations are pretty straightforward. Hope this helps.

Comment: It return null but I will check it again.

Comment: Yes there was typo After fixing that it is working.

Comment: `serialize()` is a bit of a blunt object solution. The larger and more complex the array members are, the more overhead is required to convert them back and forth and do the comparison. Also `serialize()` does not canonicalize the data and otherwise identical objects can be written as different serialized representations. https://3v4l.org/iI994

Answer (score 0):

In the place of hole in the language where `array_uunique()` *should* be [again, this was never implemented] you can use a quirk of PHP's associative arrays to enforce the uniqueness.

```php
$cars = array(array("icon"=>'sim'),array("icon"=>'airtime'),array("icon"=>'sim'));

// duplicate indexes are overwritten
$index = array_flip(array_column($cars, 'icon'));

$out = [];
foreach($index as $i) {
    $out[] = $cars[$i];
}

var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["icon"]=>
    string(3) "sim"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["icon"]=>
    string(7) "airtime"
  }
}
```

Ref:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php